# Json Parsing with multiple loops

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

How can I loop through this part of the json `[{first set of values},{data->children->data->body}` in objective c?

Json is

```
  [
      {
        "kind": "Listing"
      },
      {
        "kind": "Listing",
        "data": {
          "children": [
            {
              "data": {
                "body": "body1"
              }
            },

            {
              "data": {
                "body": "body2"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

My current code is

```
m_ArrList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *infomation = [self dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONString:@"surveyquestion.json"];
    NSArray *array=[infomation objectForKey:@"data"];
    int ndx;
    NSLog(@"%@",array);
    for (ndx = 0; ndx < [array count]; ndx++) {
        NSDictionary *stream = (NSDictionary *)[array objectAtIndex:ndx];

        NSArray *string=[stream valueForKey:@"children"];

        //i am stuck here
    }
```

What do I do at the "//i am stuck here" ?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add the values of  `@"children"` dictionary in an array and then parse that array to get the data inside children

```
[childrenArray addObject:[stream objectForKey:@"children"]];

   // finally parse childrenArray
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// You Just need to Implement following Lines and you will get all the data for Key Body in children array
NSDictionary *infomation = [self dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONString:@"surveyquestion.json"];

NSArray *string= [[infomation objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"children"];

[string enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger ind, BOOL *stop){
    NSLog(@"Body : %@",[[obj objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"body"]);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSJSONSerialization` try to implement this. Here you need to pass `NSString` as jsonStr which you need to read from your file.

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
id allValues = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                               options:0
                                                 error:&jsonError];

if(jsonError!=nil)
    NSLog(@"Json_Err: %@",jsonError);

NSArray *array=allValues;

for (int ndx = 0; ndx < [array count]; ndx++) {
    NSDictionary *stream = (NSDictionary *)[array objectAtIndex:ndx];
    NSLog(@"%@",[stream objectForKey:@"kind"]);

    NSArray *child = [[stream objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"children"];

    //i am stuck here

    for(int i =0; i <[child count];i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *childData = (NSDictionary *)[child objectAtIndex:i];
        //NSLog(@"%@",[childData objectForKey:@"data"]);
        NSLog(@"%@",[[childData objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"body"]);
    }
}
```